# Android talkback does not announce "selected" state

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have some items in bottomsheet, all the items have content description.

When user opens this bottom sheet one the item is "selected" and I want to announcement to have prefix "selected"  before talkback announces description of the button.

So I have done the following -- have extension function below, that correctly draws focuses on selected item.

```
    private fun View.accessibilityFocus(): View {
        this.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null)
        this.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED)
        this.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
        return this
    }
```

I invoke this `accessibilityFocus` as shown below, even do it with a delay

```
                if (isCurrentlySelectedTab) {
                        uiHandler.postDelayed(
                            {
                                selectedView.requestFocus()
                                selectedView.accessibilityFocus()
                            },
                            ACCESSIBILITY_DELAY,
                        )
                }
```

The accessibility focus certainly moves to this selected item. Only thing that I can't figure out for life me, is how do I get talkback to announce "selected" prefix automatically. I don't want to artificially add the prefix selected, if I don't have to.

Comment: Can you include your button implementation?